# How to convert Spacy Model .pkl file into .pt/.pth pytorch supported format

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, spacy

I have spacy model which I am using for inference in .pkl format. The datatype of .pkl file is <class 'spacy.lang.en.English'>. I want to make inference script run on GPU. I tried using different methods using spacy gpu, numba etc.

```
import spacy  
spacy.prefer_gpu() # or spacy.require_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load("content/path")
```

It didn't work, I think by converting the .pkl into .pt will work by loading the pt file to 'cuda' device. Please suggest approach to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout way of converting .pkl file to a .pt or .pth file would be to flatten the .pkl file, and then initialize a new model with the same shapes. If you then reload the flatten weights and save that to .pth, it may work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).